# Is there an html special character for a down-right arrow?

Tags: html, unicode, special-characters

I'm posting a few audio files on my website, and for some of them they have videos.  I would like to have it laid out like this:

AUDIO FILE:

|

-->  VIDEO FILE

I know that

```
&crarr;
```

makes a carriage return (↵), but I don't know a way to make that face the opposite way.

Comment: ➥ (U+2785), ➘ (U+2798), [other options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Dingbats).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want Unicode codepoint U+21B3  ↳

You should be able to type

```
&#8627;
```

in the document. But be aware that not all your users may have the glyph for this character on their computer.

Comment: Interesting.  What happens if the user doesn't have the glyph?  Does it simply not show? I would be fine with that, but if there's some kind of error message then I would definitely avoid it.

Comment: @PearSquirrel It will usually show some sort of default "not found" glyph.  On my computer it's the "empty box" glyph, as seen on lines 80 and 90 of [this image](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/mathml/fonts/encoding/symbol.gif).  Your mileage may vary based on character sets installed, operating system, etc.

Comment: There definitely shouldn't be an error message. As rockerest suggests, a symbol consisting of a character-sized dashed box is often used to represent "not available", if it is large enough the box may enclose the code 21BC representing this specific codepoint. On Macs I believe it's sometimes a characteristic symbol from the missing range (e.g. if you're missing Hebrew it might be an Aleph in a box, if musical notation, a semi-quaver in a box, that sort of thing)

Comment: Isn't it actually `\u21b3` for `↳`? `\u21bc` yields `↼` on my computer.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no HTML entity for a downward arrow with a corner rightwards but you can get it with a numeric character reference (see below).  Of course, you can also use an image.

`&#8627;` will render the Unicode character you are looking for, assuming your document is using a compatible charset and your browser supports it.

Comment: This isn't true: &#8627; is the character.

Answer (score 1):

don't depend on extended characters like these. you will usually end up with cross-browser character issues. use images instead.

p.s: if you really want to go that way, webdings3 has that character (0x39 character code). you can check it from Windows' `Character Map Editor` (`charmap.exe`) tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ↳ (`&#8627;`)for the character you want.  However, as @Emir says, you shouldn't rely on extended characters.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html for an entire list of arrows. Multiple styles and options are available.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before posting here.  I was hoping there was an alternative to using unicode. :(

Comment: @PearSquirrel: `&crarr;` is as much unicode as `&#8627;`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html down where it says "Arrows"

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I meant that I didn't want to use something that wasn't an original html character.  Emir was on the dot when he said I shouldn't rely on extended characters.

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS transforms you could transform the character.

```
<span style='-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1)'>&crarr;</span>
```

[Cross browser Css transforms](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)